# Converting string to datetime works with select but nor update (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, sqldatetime, sql-convert

I have a table in my database that has has both the original user input date string, then tries to get the datetime from that by using CONVERT

```
CREATE TABLE #UserInput 
(
    actualDate DATETIME NULL,
    dateString VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

The statement

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, dateString) 
FROM #UserInput
```

works fine, and correctly converts the strings to datetime.

However, when I try to set the `actualDate` column, using the statement

```
UPDATE X 
SET X.actualDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, X.dateString) 
FROM #UserInput X
```

I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Since I can run the select, I know all the dateStrings are formatted correctly and can be converted. So then why am I unable to do so with the update?

The specific format I've been testing with is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm, but the solution would need to handle other formats as well.

I appreciate any help on this, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling CONVERT with the style argument to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: What data does the table hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #UserInput (
actualDate datetime NULL,
dateString varchar(50) NULL)

insert #UserInput(dateString) values('20181231 12:15')

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, dateString) 
FROM #UserInput 

UPDATE X 
SET X.actualDate = CONVERT(datetime, X.dateString) 
FROM #UserInput X 

select * from #UserInput
```

I tested it for two format yyyymmdd hh:mm and mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm this code working correctly. I didn't get any error for update or select run.

Comment: Turns out it was working correctly the whole time, I was getting the same error elsewhere and I hadn't realized it. Sorry for starting this goose chase

Answer (score 0):

The simply solution is `try_convert()`:

```
UPDATE X 
    SET X.actualDate = TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, X.dateString) 
    FROM #UserInput X ;
```

I suspect the problem is that you are not seeing *all* the rows in `X` -- just a few that match.  To test this, run:

```
select X.*
from #userinput X
where try_convert(datetime, x.dateString) is null;
```

Comment: When I use TRY_CONVERT, I'm getting the error: "'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: @M.McCrary . . . `TRY_CONVERT()` has been available since SQL Server 2012.  Check your compatibility level (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017).  Anything at or over 110 should work.